# How can you make an HTTP GET request OVER a socket using NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, sockets, http, get

I'm working with a hardware device (I did not create) that has a standard way to communicate with it over a socket connection. The device initiates the socket connection by contacted my server(NodeJS server in question).

I have been successful in setting up a socket connection with...

```
var socketServer = net.createServer()
.listen(9999, function(){
        console.log('SOCKET Listening at: http://localhost:9999');
});

socketServer.on('connection', function(sock) {
    console.log('CONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +':'+ sock.remotePort);
    console.log(sock);
    // Need to fire HTTP GET HERE
});
```

However, I now need to send a HTTP GET request over that socket connection. So far the only way I can figure out how to do this is to **manually** socket.write the GET myself.

What I'm hoping for is some class like http that allows you to do something like...

```
http.get(socket, function(res){  // Handler code  })
```

I'm almost positive the issue is do to me being a newb at NodeJS, so I spent about 3-4 hours scouring stackoverflow and google for an answer with so far no success.

Answer (score 10):

Figured it out! Thanks @peter-lyons for the suggestion. However, the answer was rather simple and I just needed to read further into the NodeJS docs around the **net.Socket** Class.

The secret was two fold...
1) in the NodeJS docs for [net.Socket](http://nodemanual.org/latest/nodejs_ref_guide/net.html#net.Socket) it explains that class can be used as a client with **Socket.event.connect**.

2) I needed to **.write** the HTTP GET manually. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346911/creating-a-tcp-socket-with-net-createconnectionport-host-in-node-js) helped me to the answer.

Here is how I did it. Please feel free to comment on this method.

```
var socketServer = net.createServer()
.listen(9999, function(){
        console.log('SOCKET SERVER Listening at: http://localhost:9999');
});

socketServer.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('SERVER CONNECTED: ' + socket.remoteAddress +':'+ socket.remotePort);

    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('SOCKET RESPONSE: ' + data);
    }).on('connect', function() {
        socket.write("GET /rest/whoami HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n");
        console.log('SOCKET GET REQUEST SEND');
    }).on('end', function() {
        console.log('SOCKET ENDED');
    });

});
```

... and [BOOM](http://screencast.com/t/I7wgy2UI3Y4l)

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be:

- create a new instance of http.OutgoingMessage (https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/_http_outgoing.js)
- take your connected socket and set it as the message's connection: `message.connection = sock`
- call the other methods on it as normal (`writeHead` etc)

No idea if that will actually work, but seems worth trying.